# Catching "Server not found" exception

Tags: exception, xul, xulrunner

In a standalone XUL app, I'd like to catch the `server not found` exception. I've tried by  checking state in `onStateChange` event of the `nsIWebProgressListener`, but this doesn't seem to work. My `onStateChange` event implementation is as shown below. I'm making the assumption that if `STATE_START` or `STATE_STOP` is not returning a valid value, then there's something wrong with page loading, and displays the error message to the user.

```
onStateChange: function(aProgress, aRequest, aFlag, aStatus) {
  const STATE_START = Components.interfaces.nsIWebProgressListener.STATE_START;
  const STATE_STOP = Components.interfaces.nsIWebProgressListener.STATE_STOP; 

  if(aFlag & STATE_START) {
      document.getElementById("progressBar").hidden = false;
  }
  if(aFlag & STATE_STOP) {
      setTimeout(function() { document.getElementById("progressBar").hidden = true; }, 2000);     
  }

  if(aFlag & (!STATE_START | !STATE_STOP)) {
    alert("Your connection seems to be down. Please confirm with your system admin.");    
  }
  return 0;
```

},

Can someone kindly advice me on what I'm doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you be a little more specific about what you are doing? If I understand correctly, you are trying to load a URL into a `<browser>` element and are concerned about an exception appearing in the Error Console? What does that exception say **exactly**?

Comment: I'm developing a desktop app that acts as a gateway to an online service. The online service launches in a browser element. I want to be able to tell if there is no Internet access, and display an appropriate message to the user. The is loaded using the `loadURI()` method. I've tried surrounding this in a try catch block as shown: `try { document.getElementById("browser-id").loadURI("http://www.online-service.com");
  } catch(e) {
   alert("Your Internet connection seems to be down. Please consult your network admin.");
  }`, but the catch block is not being executed.

Comment: Of course not, DNS resolution is an asynchronous action - you cannot expect getting an exception synchronously there. Please edit your question and add the `nsIWebProgressListener` code you tried, that's the correct approach and you must have made a mistake somewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `onStateChange` parameter indicating whether there was a connection error is `aStatus`. For example you could use [`Components.isSuccessCode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Components.isSuccessCode):

```js
if ((aFlag & STATE_STOP) && !Components.isSuccessCode(aStatus))
{
  alert("Your connection seems to be down. Please confirm with your system admin.");
}
```

You could also compare `aStatus` with `Components.results.NS_ERROR_UNKNOWN_HOST` which corresponds to the "Server not found" error. If the connection is down there could be a number of other errors however, e.g. `NS_ERROR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` (connection failed), `NS_ERROR_UNKNOWN_PROXY_HOST` (proxy not found), `NS_ERROR_OFFLINE` (attempt to connect while in offline state). You can find the complete list of network error codes in [nsNetError.h](http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/netwerk/base/public/nsNetError.h).

Comment: Thank you Palant. `if ((aFlag & STATE_STOP) && (aStatus == Components.results.NS_ERROR_UNKNOWN_HOST)) {
        alert("Your connection seems to be down. Please confirm with your network admin.");
     }` works very well. But the code as stated above throws an exception even when there's a connection.

Comment: There are different error codes, most of them don't mean that the user is offline - you should check which one you get.

Comment: Thanks. I've implemented error checking for NS_ERROR_UNKNOWN HOST, NS_ERROR_CONNECTION_REFUSED, NS_ERROR_OFFLINE, and NS_ERROR_UNKNOWN_PROXY. The app includes links to the online service, so the user is not required to enter a URL. Indeed there's no provision for a user to enter a URL. I think this limits the range of errors that the user can encounter.